# Batch reading error (Train Schedulling) on Java NetBeans

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, bigdata, dispatcher

I am currently enrolled in a Real Time class and I need to program an adaption to a workload-scheduler module of hybrid big data (stream) system.

I am starting from scratch: using Java on NetBeans, generating synthetic dataset, reading this data set with a Thread.

So what's going on: My thread is supposed to take different file readings and, depending on the size of the file, send it to a different ArrayList on my execution. It works fine for small files such as <10KB, but I also need to I/O batch files with size 64MB+ and medium files with variable size between 1KB and 64MB. Each one of these files will be treated accordingly.

Problem: My thread(single) reads all small .txt, but when reading larger files, my NetBeans just keep running and don't really do anything.
Could it be memory problems?
Does anyone have any knowledge of how to manipulate large txt files in NetBeans?
P.S.: Memory is not an issue on my computer.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java you can read entire file into memory with:

[java.nio.file.Files.readAlLines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines)

Or you can use streaming with `java.util.Scanner` which reads file line by line or by token that matches pattern:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = null;
Scanner sc = null;
try {
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
    sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        // System.out.println(line);
    }
    // note that Scanner suppresses exceptions
    if (sc.ioException() != null) {
        throw sc.ioException();
    }
} finally {
    if (inputStream != null) {
        inputStream.close();
    }
    if (sc != null) {
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

So to read large txt files use `Scanner`.